# Matlab "Index exceeds the number of array elements." error

Tags: matlab

I have this matlab code, and it it supposed to take user input of a function, a limit, and threshold error. Then it uses the formula |f(n) - L| < error, and counts how many iterations of n is needed in order to hold that formula true. this is my code, but I keep getting this error:

Warning: Too many FOR loop iterations. Stopping after 9223372036854775806 iterations.

> In untitled (line 13)

Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 2.

Error in untitled (line 14)
if (abs(f(n) - L) <= err)

This is my code:

```
prompt = "input a function: ";
f = input(prompt,"s");
prompt = "input a limit: ";
L = input(prompt);
prompt = "input the error threshold: ";
err = input(prompt);

 for n = 1:inf
     if (abs(f(n) - L) <= err)
       break;
    end
end

 disp(n)
```

I tried figuring out what the problem is, but I am not really sure, if anyone could help me understand, that would be great.

Comment: What’s the text of the input function look like?

Comment: Your `f` input is a character array, but you’re treating it like a function. Depending on what it looks like, you need to send it through `eval`, `str2func`, or something similar.